# viewport on load / resize find class remove jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, viewport

I'm using jQuery with viewport to find a class and remove it based on window width.

Figured we have the desktop version which we target with resize and the mobile version with reload. code works good but one problem on destkop.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
    if (viewportWidth < 600) {
        $(".dropdown-toggle").removeClass("disabled");
    }
 });

$(window).resize(function () {
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
    if (viewportWidth < 600) {
        $(".dropdown-toggle").removeClass("disabled");
    }
});

$(window).load(mobileViewUpdate);
$(window).resize(mobileViewUpdate);
```

I'm getting this error stating:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: mobileViewUpdate is not defined

looking at this code what am I doing wrong here to get this error?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm getting this error stating:
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: mobileViewUpdate is not defined

Exactly: you're calling a function called `mobileViewUpdate()`, but there is no such function defined in your code. Also, even if `mobileViewUpdate()` existed, calling it would be unnecessary since you already have anonymous functions within the `load` and `resize` events that are doing what you need.

So, for starters, you can simply remove these two lines:

```
$(window).load(mobileViewUpdate);
$(window).resize(mobileViewUpdate);
```

In addition, your two anonymous functions are identical – they just fire on different events. So you can merge them like this:

```
$(window).on("load resize", function() {
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
    if (viewportWidth < 600) {
        $(".dropdown-toggle").removeClass("disabled");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this code, mobileViewUpdate isn't defined anywhere in it.

Comment: I'm doing this code from a /main.js file included at the bottom fo the page. not inline. how would it look with the mobileViewUpdate defined?

Answer (score 0):

after playing around for a while I was able to do it this way. not sure if it's the most optimal way but it works great.

```
$(window).resize (function() {
        // This will fire each time the window is resized:
        if($(window).width() <= 600) {$(".dropdown-toggle").removeClass("disabled");}
        })
     .resize ();

     $(window).load (function() {
        // This will fire each time the window is resized:
        if($(window).width() <= 600) {$(".dropdown-toggle").removeClass("disabled");}
        })
.load ();
```

I should get a new badge for figuring this out on my own!!! :)